# Error while creating new project with Play 2.3

Tags: scala, sbt, playframework-2.3

I am using scala 2.11.1, sbt 0.13.5 and Play 2.3. I am facing problem while creating new project

When I run

```
activator new sampleapp play-scala
```

it creats a directory with name "sampleapp"

then when I go into the directory and run `activator` command it gives error

here is my autogenerated sbt file

```
name := """demo"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  cache,
  ws,
  specs2 % Test
)

resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"

// Play provides two styles of routers, one expects its actions to be injected, the
// other, legacy style, accesses its actions statically.
routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
```

here are my stack traces

> scalaworkspace/sessiondemo$ activator [info] Loading project
>   definition from /home/ahsen/scalaworkspace/demo/project error:
>   error while loading , zip file is empty
>   scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object scala.runtime
>   in compiler mirror not found.
>
> at
>   scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.signal(MissingRequirementError.scala:16)
>       at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.notFound(MissingRequirementError.scala:17)
>       at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:48)
>       at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:40)
>       at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:61)
>       at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:28)
>       at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
>       at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:129)
>       at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
>       at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:36)
>       at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
>       at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:19)
>       at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:44)
>       at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:20)
>       at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala) [error] scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object scala.runtime
>   in compiler mirror not found. [error] Use 'last' for the full log.
>   Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?

Answer (score 0):

As I know, injected generator, i.e. **routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator**, is only supported in Play 2.4.

Take a look at this.
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration24